# Hide <nav> on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, nav

Created a little nav for a client that opens a 'site map' style of links which is popular opposed to the menu-after-menu of the past and it's worked great.

Opens on click, and hides once the mouse leaves the div. However, now I've run into an issue now that we've introduced anchor links to that nav. With it ONLY going away once the mouse leaves, the page will go to the anchor link requested behind the nav, but not go away until the mouse leaves.

I thought I could just add a line to move it on click, but that doesn't do anything. I changed the action to make the background red just to make sure it was triggering and it does, but it just doesn't want to adjust the top (the way I'm hiding) as it does the others. Hoping someone can have a look and tell me what I'm missing! Thanks guys

Here's the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#nav_hover").click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#nav_features #nav_expanded_nav.expanded_nav").css("top", "95px");
    }, 20);
});
$("#nav_hover").mouseleave(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#nav_features #nav_expanded_nav.expanded_nav").css("top", "-800px");
    }, 800);
});

});
```

Here's the nav bar the 'expanded nav' drops from:

```
<nav id="main_nav">
 <ul>
  <a id="nav_hover">
  <li>Nav Option</li>
  </a>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

And this is the expanded nav that comes down, that I want to hide whenever clicked:

```
<nav id="nav_expanded_nav" class="expanded_nav">
 <ul class="main_catagory_nav">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Description</p>
   <li><a href="http://www.theplace.com/link.shtml#anchor">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://www.theplace.com/link.shtml#anchor2">Link 2</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

And this is what I THOUGHT would be all I needed!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#nav_hover").click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#nav_features #nav_expanded_nav.expanded_nav").css("top", "95px");
    }, 20);
});
$("#nav_hover").mouseleave(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#nav_features #nav_expanded_nav.expanded_nav").css("top", "-800px");
    }, 800);
});
$(".nav_expanded_nav a").click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#nav_features #nav_expanded_nav.expanded_nav").css("top", "-800px");
    }, 20);
});


});
```

But it does nothing. If I change iut to `.css("background", "red")` it does change the background of that div just fine, which at least confirms it's the right idea. but it just can't impact the 'top' of css

Comment: post a JSfiddle, i'll have a look for you.

Comment: do you want to show/hide the expanded nav on click ?

Comment: Huh, seems like nothing wants to work inside jsfiddle.

Comment: Hey cchacholiades,
I do, basically there are a bunch of nav options in the main bar, and a site-map style div that expands (shows) below that and hides when you move off the div. Looking to also hide it when a link is clicked. Normally not an issue as going to a new page loads with the nav hidden but currently anchor clicks are causing an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This my attempt: make the `#nav_expanded_nav` always `hidden`. Then when `#nav_hover` its clicked change the `visibility` to `visible`. When an anchor tag is clicked inside the `#nav_expanded_nav` change its visibility back to `hidden` The same happens when the user leaves the `#nav_expanded_nav`.

**CSS**:

```
#nav_expanded_nav {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nav_hover").click(function() {
      $("#nav_expanded_nav").css("visibility", "visible");
  });

  $("#nav_expanded_nav > ul > li > a ").click(function() {
      $('#nav_expanded_nav').css("visibility", "hidden");
  });

  $("#nav_expanded_nav").mouseleave(function(){
     $(" #nav_expanded_nav").css("visibility", "hidden");
  });                                                            
});
```

See an **[example pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qddvop)**.

Comment: NAILED IT! I revised it to still have it 'slide' in, but used the visibility hidden to hide the nav for the anchor links and it works perfectly, thank you! Added another line with the $("#nav_features #nav_expanded_nav.expanded_nav").css("top", "95px"); to also set visibility to visble, and everything works great!